# tightvnc black screen server Fedora 13 , client windows XP

Tags: client, vnc

I get a black screen with the above setup. I have tried RealVNC and TigerVNC clients too on windows with the same result.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Any luck with your problem? Did my answer help? If so can you select it?

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for my late response. My problem turned out to be quite lame actually :) I had enabled confirm user on my Fedora box's remote connections setting. When I was trying to access it via tightvnc client remotely, fedora box was spitting out confirmation messages leaving me with a black screen. I disabled that option and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your VNC server is running, but there is nothing running in it; no window manager, no desktop environment (GNOME), etc.

That probably means you ran the VNC server directly without using some of the friendly wrapper scripts such as vncserver. For example, if you run Xtightvnc directly, that's what you'll get.

For example, on Ubuntu I usually start a VNC session (or port 5901) like this which starts the VNC/X-server and the normal desktop environment:

vncserver -geometry 1024x768 :1

On Ubuntu `vncserver` is a link to `tightvncserver`. If you don't have `vncserver` on Fedora 13 then try `tightvncserver`.